# How to call an async method that is guaranteed to be sync

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, async-await

I have a method that more or less looks like this:

```
public async Task PossiblyAsync(bool amIlucky)
{
    if (amIlucky)
        await Task.Delay(9000);

    return;
}
```

In some cases I know for sure that no async codepathes will be called in it, but still I need to do everything async to the very top. Which is not a problem in itself, but I wonder if it will introduce some unnecessary overhead when a perfectly sync code pretends to be async, wrapping all the results in `Task<T>` and doing who-knows-what else.

Also, I would really like for it to not jump between threads. I'm not sure whether it can happen, especially since there is no synchronization context in asp net core. But then again, I don't quite understand what a synchronization context even is :)

What would be the most correct way to call such a method?

Comment: `return Task.Delay(9000);` is wrong. It should be `await Task.Delay(9000);`

Comment: Do you `await PossiblyAsync()` a million times in a loop? If yes, change the return value of the method to `ValueTask` instead of `Task`. If not, there is nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 3):

You can rewrite the method to avoid the generation of the code that gets generated when you make a method async:

```
public Task PossiblyAsync(bool amIlucky)
{
    if (amIlucky)
        return Task.Delay(9000);

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

You can do this as your method doesn't need to do anything after the `Task.Delay` has completed.

`Task.CompletedTask` is always in the completed state, so when your method is called with `false` there won't be any memory allocation.

Comment: Ok, I got it. But the question remains how should I invoke such a method? Even if the method is written without the 'async' keyword, the caller still assumes it is.

Comment: @Morse - It will depend on what the caller does. If it's an `async` method then it may choose to `await` it in some way. If it isn't then it may opt to return the task up the call stack to its caller.

Answer (score 3):

> but I wonder if it will introduce some unnecessary overhead when a perfectly sync code pretends to be async, wrapping all the results in Task and doing who-knows-what else.

It isn't *usually* too bad; the state machinery builder tries to optimize for this case, and avoid everything unnecessary - returning `Task.CompletedTask` when possible. For methods that return `Task<T>`, however, this is not as readily available - you might want to switch to `ValueTask<T>` instead, as this is more efficient in the "often synchronous but needs to return a value" case. In very hot path code (usually in IO libraries), an extra layer here is often added to avoid the state machinery **entirely** until we know that we're going async, but this is niche and probably beyond what you need.

---

For an example of the "avoid the state machinery" pieces (and again emphasizing that most **application** code will never need this level of optimization), consider:

```cs
ValueTask<Foo> SomeMethodAsync(...)
{
    ValueTask<Bar> theThing = DoTheThingAsync(...); // some other things that we need
    if (theThing.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
    {
        return new ValueTask<Foo>(ProcessResults(theThing.Result));
    }
    else
    {
        return Awaited(theThing);
    }

    static async ValueTask<Foo> Awaited(ValueTask<Bar> incomplete)
        => ProcessResults(await incomplete.ConfigureAwait(false));

    static Foo ProcessResults(Bar bar) {...whatever...}
```

Comment: @AntonTykhyy lol, I misread that; I read it as explicitly *wanting* to jump thread; will remove that bit, ta

Answer (score 1):

If all the `await`s are awaiting things that are already completed, this introduces little overhead. The whole `async/await` feature has been under constant optimization for years to introduce as little overhead as possible. In particular, the `async` state machines have been made `struct`s so that they can be allocated on the stack as local variables, and are only elevated to the heap when a continuation has to be created. The overhead on creating `class Task<>` objects is mitigated by using `struct ValueTask<>` where possible, and so on. You needn't worry unless profiling specifically shows you a big problem in a specific place.

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder if it will introduce some unnecessary overhead when a perfectly sync code pretends to be async, wrapping all the results in Task and doing who-knows-what else.

Yes; a `Task<T>` is created. That's the only overhead when possibly-asynchronous code runs synchronously. Usually, you can completely ignore that overhead. If this code is called tightly in a loop or something like that, then you would want to avoid those extra allocations, which you can do by using `ValueTask<T>` instead of `Task<T>`.

> Also, I would really like for it to not jump between threads.

It won't. Synchronous code - by definition - waits for the code to complete before continuing on the same thread. This is also true of code that *could* be asynchronous but runs synchronously.

> What would be the most correct way to call such a method?

By `await`ing its return value, just like any other asynchronous method. That way, the callers of this method aren't taking an implicit dependency on the implementation details of this method. So if a future refactoring makes *all* code paths asynchronous, then the calling code just works without having to change.